# Module / Class Library

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Code Below, Question at the end.

```
module Vehicle
        class Car
            @car = {}
            def self.create_my_car(options={})
                if @car.any?
                    puts "but you already have a car!"
                    return
                end
                if options.key?(:type) 
                    if options[:type] == 'small'
                        @car.merge!(wheels: '3')
                    elsif options[:type] == 'huge'
                        @car.merge!(wheels: '8')
                    elsif options[:type] == 'normal'
                        @car.merge!(wheels: '4')
                    end
                else
                    @car.merge!(wheels: '4')            
                end
            end

            def self.my_car(options={})
                create_my_car unless @@car
                puts "car has 4 wheels"
            end

            def self.specs(options={})
                puts @car.to_s
            end
        end
    end
```

**Call the module from controller action**

```
class CarsController < ApplicationController
   def create
      Vehicle::Car.create_my_car(params)
      Vehicle::Car.specs
   end
end
```

**Perform Action**

Request 1 (Good)

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/cars?type=small
{:wheels=>"3"}
but you already have a car!
```

Request 2 (Bad) instance already exists. **type=huge should create a car with 8 wheels but the instance already exists** from the previous request

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/cars?type=huge
{:wheels=>"3"}
but you already have a car!
```

What is the best approach to having a module/class last only for the duration of the controller request? In other words, I do not want request 2 to be using data from request 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the best approach to having a module/class last only for the duration of the controller request? In other words, I do not want request 2 to be using data from request 1

In this case, **don't** use class-level data. Store your specs in instances of the class, not the class itself.